# Searching an algorithm to generate Tectonic/Seguru puzzle

Tags: algorithms

I'm trying to write a program that generates a Tectonic/Seguru puzzle, and I'm struggling to find an algorithm that can generate them

[The rules of the puzzle are here](https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/1077888), but basically, it involves a grid that's divided into components, and the goal is to fill the grid with numbers according to these 2 rules :

- A component of n cells contains each integer from 1 to n exactly once
- Two adjacent cells (including diagonally) cannot have the same number in them

So far, the only method I could find for generating a grid is generating random grids (possibly unsolvable) and trying to solve them, until i find a grid that is solvable

Obviously that's a terribly inefficient algorithm, but i couldn't find anything that would be more powerful

Does someone knows of an algorithm that could be useful in this situation ?

Answer (score 1):

One way that puzzles *like* this (not necessarily *exactly* this) are often generated is to use a solver to test candidate solutions.

We'll assume that you generate a polyomino tessellation first, and I'll assume that this isn't a challenge for you. The real difficulty is adding just enough clues to give the puzzle a unique solution.

What makes this style of puzzle tractable (as with Sudoku) is that each cell can only contain one of a small number of possible values. So if you have a solver which answers the yes/no question "can the grid be *completed* given these clues", you can in principle just test them all.

Taking the linked example:

[image]

What numbers could possibly go in row 1 column 6? It's in a pentomino, so you are limited to the values 1 through 5. You can test a value, say the value 1, by adding that as a "clue", and then asking the solver if the rest of the grid can be completed. If not, then 1 is not a possible value in that cell.

Once you have done this for a cell, then there are three possibilities:

1. There are no possible values that can go in the cell. Then the puzzle has no solution.
2. There is exactly one possible value that can go in the cell.
3. There is more than one possible value that can go in the cell. Then this gives you a cell which could be a potential new clue.

If all of the cells have only one possible value that can go into them, the puzzle has a unique solution.

Writing a solver can be straightforward if it can be reduced to a problem like [exact cover](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dancing_Links), or you could use a drop-in [SAT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SAT_solver) solver. As an optimisation, solvers often prove that a grid has a feasible completion by generating that completion, and any such completion gives you a collection of "possible values" for some grid cells that don't need to be tested.